# Unicode/HTML question about obscure Greek character

Tags: html, unicode

I'm putting an old text into HTML. Sometimes it uses Greek terms and phrases. But there's one character I've never seen before. It seems to be a combination of two other characters: small omicron (`&omicron;`, ο) + small upsilon with perispomeni (`&#8166;`, ῦ). Here is a PNG illustrating the character, and how it works:

[image: upsilon, etc]

Does anyone know how to put this character into HTML? Can it be found anywhere in Unicode? Has anyone even heard of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a ligature. I couldn't find any Unicode character for that one, though there is the Latin version of it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ou_(ligature)

Which mentions the Greek.

Comment: +1. I guess you could try following a Latin OU with a U+0342 COMBINING GREEK PERISPOMENI, though the results are unlikely to be pretty. Unicode's position seems to be that you should be writing GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON then GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON WITH PERISPOMENI, and having the font with an optional ligature for the greek OU.